# Hibernate saving child entity without inserting parent

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I want to insert a new child records, where parent relations already exists in the database, without having to first fetch the parent by query and then insert the new child.

**Example:** I have a product entity, who has a ManyToOne with an existing Catalog entity:

```
@NotNull
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "catalog_id",
  referencedColumnName = "id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_product_catalog"))
private Catalog catalog;
```

I want to be able to insert a new product in a catalog, without having to first query the catalog to fill up the new product entity.

In fact, I'm receiving a json in a POST in a restController, the Json contains the product attribute and the catalog id.

Here is the Json:

```
{
  "id":1,
  "attribute1":"value",
  "catalog":{"id":1}
}
```

Once serialization occurs, the Product instance is correctly formed containing an instance of Catalog which only have the id field value.

I'm receiving this message on insert:

> Attempting to save one or more entities that have a non-nullable
>   association with an unsaved transient entity

I understand why I receive this message, I also could get the Catalog row from the database but this would mean I have to query all parents each time I insert a child row which makes no sense at all designwise since I'm really only inserting a row with a foreign key references.

Does anybody know how to prevent this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you create a separate property for catalog_id and put the @NotNull constraint there instead of the Catalog object property?

Comment: I initially wanted to have the database ddl generated by hibernate, I'm still trying to make it work that way.  I would also like that catalog be eager fetch when I select a product from the database.  But if I insert a product, I only want the catalogId the be insert in the product row, without having an additional select executed for the catalog part.

Comment: Seems like a very very standard functionnality to me.  I want to eager fetch on select, but I want to insert only the product entity, and let the database enforce the foreign key constraint if the catalog don't exists.

Comment: I tried what you propose and it solve the problem.  By keeping the ManyToOne relation to Catalog (with insert and update =false) and adding a catalog_id field, I can now insert only the product entity by having only the id of the parent relations.   Still, having duplicates in the entity (Having both the catalog.id and the catalod_id field) could cause problem in the long term, but it's better than doing multiple useless selects on inserts.